# How to run an asynctask inside an Alarmmanager?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an asynctask which consumes a webservice. Now I need to execute the asynctask once a day, at a certain hour. 
What I want to do is call doinbackground event of the asynctask inside the AlarmManager. I have read about using AlarmManager but there is no documentation about using it with asynctask. 
Am I going to the right direction?
Any advice will highly apreciate

Comment: Why don't you use [__IntentService__](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to do your WebService stuff as you are doing once a day at certain hour.

Comment: As bharat says, you should use an `IntentService` instead of `AsyncTask`. You'll need to create an alarm which sends a broadcast at the required time. Use a `BroadcastReceiver` to 'listen' for the broadcast and then have it start the `IntentService`. There are a lot of code samples on the internet and also here on Stack Overflow - just do some searching.

Comment: @bharat I'm confused about why not use asynctask since the docs says that it should ideally be used for short operations, as the calling to the webservice..

Comment: You can call AsyncTask only on UI thread. U are using AlarmManager which trigger event at certain time (may be app is not running that time) and doing webservice stuff , in this situation using IntentService is the best practice. While IntentService runs even if your app is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create an alarm manager which runs once in a day.
Time you can set according to your requirements. Here I set it at 7am.

```
int REPEATING_TIME = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 06);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        Intent i = new Intent(context, DemoService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context,
                202, i,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar.getTimeInMillis(), REPEATING_TIME, pi);
```

Step 2 : Create an asynctask class and do the background operation there you want to perform.

```
public class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return "response";
    }

}
```

Step 3 : Create a class which extends the Service.

```
    public class DemoService extends Service {

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            new LoadData(){}protected void onPostExecute(String result){
// anything you want to perform onPost.
};}.execute("API URL");

            stopSelf();
            return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Using `AsyncTask` in a `Service` is a pointless exercise as `AsyncTask` is designed to interact with the UI (and a `Service` doesn't have a UI). Much better to simply use an `IntentService` which manages its own worker thread and shuts itself down when the work is complete.

Comment: your point is right but sometimes we don't need to perform the UI related tasks. Like we simply wants to update the db etc.